# OpenGL textures fails on Motorola Milestone

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, milestone

I have troubles with OpenGL textures on Motorola Milestone with 2.1 firmware. Each call to glGenTextures fails with error GL_INVALID_OPERATION and sets the id with random numbers. The exact same application works on G1 without any error.

Does anybody have a hands-on experience with a similar issue and knows a way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: the GL error was actually on glTexImage2d, because I was using `3` for `internalFormat` and `GL_RGB` for `format`. After setting both to `GL_RGB` errors went away

Comment: Yes, I was mislead because glGenTextures returned random big numbers for ID, not the expected 1, 2, 3... I was tired when asking, and produced a stupid question